# If statement in react => Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [totalPeople, setTotalPeople] = useState(1);

    if ( value1 > value2 ) {
        setTotalPeople(totalPeople + 1)
        return totalPeople

    }
```

Im trying to add 1 to the total of people everytime the first value is bigger then the second one, i keep getting this re-render error. What is the best way to solve this problem ?

Comment: The code makes little sense on its own.

Comment: If `value1` nor `value2` change, your functional component is going to keep setting the state with `setTotalPeople`, for the condition will remain true. EDIT: that's all I could see, since you didn't provide a complete piece of code

Comment: Don't put code like that directly inside a component's main function. It causes a re-render, which runs the main function again, which causes a re-render, which runs the main function again, etc etc